# Swift Firebase UISearchController Index Out Of Range

Tags: swift, firebase, search, segue, uisearchcontroller

I have a tableview that lists all of my "places" from firebase. I have a UISearchController to obviously search through these "places". The problem is when I just tap on the UISearchController but don't type anything and select a "place" I get a index out of range error. If I am typing or do not activated the UISearchController, it segues fine. Just when it is active and don't type is when I get the error. It throws the error on "let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]"

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "BusinessProfiles" {
        // gotta check if we're currently searching
        if self.searchController.isActive  {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? BusinessProfilesViewController
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
        } else {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? BusinessProfilesViewController
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add `searchbar.text == ""` condition, if I got your problem correctly

Comment: where would I add that?

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you did not perform any search and select a place, right? If so, you call empty `filteredUsers[indexPath.row]` with indexPath.row of selected row, which have an positive index. As so, you must first check if search was perform, and only then call `filteredUsers[indexPath.row]` like this:

```
if !filteredUsers.isEmpty {
    if self.searchController.isActive  {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added this "&& searchController.searchBar.text != ""
" to correct my problem

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "BusinessProfiles" {
        // gotta check if we're currently searching
        if self.searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? BusinessProfilesViewController
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
        } else {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? BusinessProfilesViewController
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
        }
    }
}
```